# Getting error on installation of PyroCMS

Tags: php, apache, laravel, pyrocms

I am getting this error when installing PyroCMS

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\pyrocms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\pyrocms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd then go to the directory of your project.
cmd
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\yourproject
then
update composer
that's it